# Why is GC getting triggered in this situation?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, clr

I am creating an array with large number of items (number of items > 2500). The array holds the object with the structure depicted in the program below. 

I observed that the "%Time spend in GC" for the process spikes up to a high value. It starts at value with `ArraySize = 2500`. For anything below that 2500 the high %time spent in GC has a low value. ***In fact even with ArraySize=2499 the counter does not shown any increase.***

Performance counter:

[image]

Code:

```
namespace TestGC
{
    public class Line
    {
        private string _data1;
        private decimal _data2;
        private decimal _data3;

        public string Data1
        {
            get { return _data1; }
            set { _data1 = value; }
        }

        public decimal Data2
        {
            get { return _data2; }
            set { _data2 = value; }
        }

        public decimal Data3
        {
            get { return _data3; }
            set { _data3 = value; }
        }
        public Line()
        {
        }


    }


    public class Item
    {
        public const int Size = 200;
        private Line[] _lines = new Line[Size];

        public Line[] Lines
        {
            get { return _lines; }
            set { _lines = value; }
        }
    }

    public class Package
    {
        private Item _item;

        public Package()
        {
            _item = new Item();
            for (int i = 0; i < Item.Size; i++)
            {
                _item.Lines[i] = new Line();
            }
        }

        public Item Item
        {
            get { return _item; }
            set { _item = value; }
        }

    }

    class Program
    {
        private const int ArraySize = 2500;
        static Package[] array = new Package[ArraySize];
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {           
            Console.ReadLine();

            for (int i = 0; i < ArraySize; i++)
            {
                array[i] = new Package();
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Indeed, but what is the question proper?

Comment: Why is this behavior? Why is GC getting triggered?

Comment: If you're referring to a percentage, your program doesn't do anything, it will take a very short time to allocate those 2500 objects, so yes, in this context the "relative percentage of your total app runtime" will be high. Do you have a better example that takes longer time with the same high usage?

Comment: Try Line as a struct.  You don't need to new the items in a struct array.  Also try Items as a stuct.   Is there a reason for these to be classes?  Also for line include a ctor to pass the values - that is faster than using three sets.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen That is not entirely correct, try the same program with a value for ArraySize less than 2500, (even 2499); the % Time spent in GC is barely noticable

Answer (score -1):

The GC is probably reallocating stuff around. That's some expected behavior. I suggest reading about the [Large Object Heap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc534993.aspx).